# How to expand parent height in nested CSS grids when children expand

Tags: css, css-grid

I have some nested CSS grids where children grids expand past the parent grid height.

I deleted my code to the bare minimum so that I could see what was causing this but I have not been able to identify where the problem code is or how to make the parent height responsive to the children.

I suspect my main problem to be somewhere in this code here but you can see the problem here https://jsfiddle.net/bgp7fzjm/2/

```
.grid-container {
  background-color: #080808;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
  "site-card"
  "project-card";
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#site-card {
  grid-area: site-card;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
  "site1"
  "site2"
  "site3";
  grid-column-gap: 4%;
  grid-row-gap: 4%;
}
```

Ideally, the parent grid expands with the children and the children do not overflow past the background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use percentage for `grid-row-gap`. This won't work if you don't set a specific height to the parent `grid` wrapper. Percentages ( in this case ) are depending on the dimensions of the parent. Because if not, `4%` of what ? The grid won't know.

If you don't want to set a specific height, you can use `px` for the gap.

```css
.grid-container {
  background-color: #080808;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "site-card" "project-card";
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#site-card {
  grid-area: site-card;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "site1" "site2" "site3";
  grid-column-gap: 4%;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
}

#site1 {
  grid-area: site1;
}

#site2 {
  grid-area: site2;
}

#site3 {
  grid-area: site3;
}

.card {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <section id="site-card">
      <div class="card" id="site1">


      </div>
      <div class="card" id="site2">


      </div>
      <div class="card" id="site3">


      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</main>
```